# EmberJS: Insert component dynamically

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Got following components:

```
App.ParentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
   child: '',
   yieldTemplateName: 'empty_by_default',
   setup: function(){
     //append here child compoment
   }.on('didInsertElement')
});

App.ChildComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
   templateName: 'some_location',
   actions:{
     //whatever
   }
});
```

What am I wondering if is possible to add child component into parent's at any render status and based on a parameter?

So I call, for example:

```
{{parent child="child"}}
```

And it eventually renders:

```
<div !-- parent -- >
  <div !-- child -- > </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just put the child component in the parent component's template surrounded by an `if` block?

Answer (score 0):

```
App.ParentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    child: null,
    hasChild: Em.computed.notEmpty('child')
});

// parent template
{{#if hasChild}}
    {{component child}}
{{/if}}

// another template
{{parent child="child"}} {{!-- displays ChildComponent --}}
```

Note: The component helper will be available in Ember 1.11. If you are using an earlier version, you can use the ember-dynamic-component addon.